# Crantastic way of expand a vector into repeated measurements

Tags: r

Let us say I have a data frame indicating the factor level for each individual:

```
I.df = data.frame(variant = sample(x=c(0,1,2), size=30, replace = TRUE), tissue = sample(x=as.factor(c('cereb','hipo','arc')), size=30, replace = TRUE))
```

And I also have a vector with the means for each factor:

```
means.tissues = c(1.2, 3, 0.5)
names(means.tissues) = c('cereb', 'hipo', 'arc')
```

Then I want to create a vector of length equal to the number of rows of I.df, and where the value is the respective tissue for a given row.  I.e.,

```
ind.tissues = rep(NA, nrow(I.df))
for(i in 1:nrow(I.df))
{
ind.tissues[i] = means.tissues[names(means.tissues) == I.df$tissue[i]]
}
```

I think the for loop is a rather inefficient way to do this, specially for matrices with very large n, is there a better/more efficient way to do this using vectorization code in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match`:

```
ind.tissues = means.tissues[match(I.df$tissue, names(means.tissues))]
```

The `match` function returns the position in argument 2 of each element in argument 1. We then use those indices to grab the correct elements in `means.tissues`.

**Edit**: As mentioned by @Joran in the comment, since `means.tissues` is a named vector, you can look it up by name instead of using `match`:

```
ind.tissues <- means.tissues[as.character(I.df$tissue)]
```

Comment: ...or just `ind.tissues <- means.tissues[as.character(I.df$tissue)]`?

Comment: @Dnaiel it won't change the ordering

Comment: @Dnaiel I don't think so. (As long as you don't get messed up with the factor/character difference, as I initially did.)

Comment: @joran, josilber, thanks great answer, works exactly as expected!